# Connecting OLED 128x64 LCD; dogm_lcd_implementation.h is missing for patching

Tags: marlin, diy-3d-printer, firmware, full-graphic-smart-controller

I'm trying to install a MKS 12864 0.96 OLED for my DIY 3D printer (see [this other question](/q/8256)).

It's not listed in Marlin's LCD section of `configuration.h` and according to some instructions, I need to do some modification to a file  named `dogm_lcd_implementation.h` which is **missing** in Marlin 1.1.9!

Where is it? How can I install my LCD module?

Answer (score 4):

#### Question History

An [answer](/a/8260/) on your [previous question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/8256/8884) discusses patches for installing the LCD module in your Marlin printer firmware. Note that these patches are very old (around 2015). Many things have changed since then (as is acknowledged there). That [answer](/a/8260/) does not work for recent versions of Marlin source code!

#### Answer

Yes, your observation of the [`dogm_lcd_implementation.h`](https://github.com/Voxel8/Marlin/blob/master/Marlin/dogm_lcd_implementation.h) file being missing in the 1.1.9 version of Marlin is correct. But, I believe it is not lost, all code and further development can be found in [`ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h). There are some older versions of the file wondering over internet, e.g. [here](https://download.lulzbot.com/KITTAZ/software/2014Q4/firmware/Marlin/dogm_lcd_implementation.h) or [from this older Marlin cloned repository](https://github.com/Voxel8/Marlin/blob/master/Marlin/dogm_lcd_implementation.h).

I believe that your 2<sup>nd</sup> patch:

```
/*---------------MKS OLED patch_2-----------------------*/
#elif defined(U8GLIB_SSD1306)
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(23, 17, 16, 25); // SW SPI Com: SCK = 23, MOSI = 17, CS = 16, A0 = 25
/*---------------MKS OLED patch_2-----------------------*/
```

should be placed in [`ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h) just under:

```
#elif ENABLED(MINIPANEL)
  // The MINIPanel display
  //U8GLIB_MINI12864 u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // 8 stripes
  U8GLIB_MINI12864_2X u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0); // 4 stripes
```

and before:

```
#else
  // for regular DOGM128 display with HW-SPI
  //U8GLIB_DOGM128 u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // HW-SPI Com: CS, A0  // 8 stripes
  U8GLIB_DOGM128_2X u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // HW-SPI Com: CS, A0 // 4 stripes
#endif
```

to create:

```
#elif ENABLED(MINIPANEL)
  // The MINIPanel display
  //U8GLIB_MINI12864 u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // 8 stripes
  U8GLIB_MINI12864_2X u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0); // 4 stripes
#elif ENABLED(U8GLIB_SSD1306)
  // SW SPI Com: SCK = 23, MOSI = 17, CS = 16, A0 = 25
  U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(23, 17, 16, 25); 
#else
  // for regular DOGM128 display with HW-SPI
  //U8GLIB_DOGM128 u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // HW-SPI Com: CS, A0  // 8 stripes
  U8GLIB_DOGM128_2X u8g(DOGLCD_CS, DOGLCD_A0);  // HW-SPI Com: CS, A0 // 4 stripes
#endif
```

Do note that there **already exists** an entry for `U8GLIB_SSD1306`! This has to be deleted, or you need to put the code in that section (un-commenting existing code)!

E.g.

```
#elif ENABLED(U8GLIB_SSD1306)
  // Generic support for SSD1306 OLED I2C LCDs
  //U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE | U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST);  // 8 stripes
  U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64_2X u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE | U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST); // 4 stripes
```

could be altered to:

```
#elif ENABLED(U8GLIB_SSD1306)
  // Generic support for SSD1306 OLED I2C LCDs
  //U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE | U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST);  // 8 stripes
  //U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64_2X u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE | U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST); // 4 stripes
  // SW SPI Com: SCK = 23, MOSI = 17, CS = 16, A0 = 25
  U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(23, 17, 16, 25);
```

Comment: There are several lines in "ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h" where 'U8GLIB_SSD1306' is mentioned... Should I uncomment all of them or only your E.g?

Comment: with your new instruction for patch 2, I get this error:   #error "Please select no more than one LCD controller option."

Comment: @2012User That could imply that you have another LCD controller enabled in your configuration file.

Comment: I've uncommented every line in "lcd/controller selection" part of configuration.h!