# How to add a patch to "Marlin_main.cpp"?

Tags: marlin, reprap, full-graphic-smart-controller

According to this question, [MKS 12864OLED Display setup](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8256/mks-12864oled-display-setup), I need to add a patch to "`Marlin_main.cpp`" but this a large file with 14789 lines of code! I don't know where I have to put this patch. Please help me.

**patch:**

```
/*---------------MKS OLED patch_3-----------------------*/
#if defined (MKS_OLED96_128x64_FULL_GRAPHICS_CONTROLLER)
pinMode(LCD_PINS_DC, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LCD_PINS_RST, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LCD_PINS_RST , LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(LCD_PINS_RST , HIGH);
#endif
/*---------------MKS OLED patch_3-----------------------*/
```

Comment: The question you refer to has an incorrect answer, I've investigated it but never got the time to post a proper answer. If I recollect correctly, the latest version is not compatible with the suggested fix. Parts are already implemented in the code. When I have the time I will look into the problem again and post an answer. Note that I do not own such a display.

Comment: I did post an [answer](/a/8273/) on [Connecting OLED 128x64 LCD; dogm_lcd_implementation.h is missing for patching](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/connecting-oled-128x64-lcd-dogm-lcd-implementation-h-is-missing-for-patching). I guess that is part of the solution. Do note that we are active on [chat]!

Comment: Yes, thank you. but it's not working yet. I guess the patch for "Marlin_main.cpp” is needed too.

Comment: Please join in [chat] to prevent a long comment discussion. I'll be looking into it tomorrow.

Comment: I've seen that kind if ifdef in the .h file, before setup(), in other Arduno programs.  I've never had  a sketch that used  .cpp file, but I suspect if it goes there, it would be after  LCD_PINS_DC and  LCD_PINS_RST were assigned to pins.

Comment: From [your comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8256/mks-12864oled-display-setup#comment16240_9887), it seems as if @0scar's answer to the previous question fixed your issue. Therefore, closing this as a duplicate.